# Data to image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, security

In My website my server will reply raw data(a Jpeg image encrypted using a password) , when the browser receives it can i decrypt(Using the same password) the data into a image and show them as image using JavaScript.

Comment: A side note: If you send the password to the client - I'll probably be able to find it out from the various debuggers (i.e. Firebug & Google Chrome dev tools), so if you're doing it to protect the images - it may not be achieving what you want....

Comment: no i will not , only those who already know the password can decrypt it, In my way password will never be sent through net , only the image will be sent through net.

Comment: is it possible to decript a data and get the image and show it as image

Comment: Yes, but which encryption algorithm do you use?

Comment: AES encryption algorithm

Comment: If you encrypt the password and then decrypt it on the server. That's fine to me as an attacker - I'll save your encrypted password and when requesting the image I'll provide this. Encrypting the password doesn't seem to be achieving anything there. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

What is the point?

Image will be 'protected' only during transmision from server to the client. Also, to decrypt it as described, password will be saved somewhere on the client side (in javascript). So every one can see the password and algorithm.

If you want to protect data during transmision just access it via https.

Comment: I agree.  SSL (e.g. https) is a much better way to protect data during transmission and it's already implemented for you in the browser and it's trivial to use.

Answer (score 0):

First please think over your design and make sure that this is really the way you want to go for. Maybe a ordinary login system with https or htaccess protection would be more suitable.

If you really want to do it the way you described, I would do it the following way:

- convert the images to base64 format ([wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)), because handling binary data with JavaScript is nasty.
- then encrypt your images with AES and a strong key
- save the result in your database

when a client wants to access the images you should

- send the encrypted images over HTTPS
- let him enter the key (or a passphrase which will be hashed,e.g. with SHA512, to the key) in a HTML input field and read it with JavaScript
- decrypt the images using a JavaScript AES library, e.g. http://point-at-infinity.org/jsaes/
- change the src attribute of your img tag to the decrypted base64 stream.